# Ubuntu Touch - Calender App not showing sync icon on the M10 tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

I have just noticed that the sync icon is not visible on my Ubuntu M10 tablet. I can see it all OK on my Ubuntu phone, but nothing on the tablet. As a result I cannot force a sync and therefore no events are showing in my calendar. Has anyone else noticed this or is there a setting I need to activate? I have done a quick search but cannot see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I got my pro 5. What it was is that I had added my gmail calander account when I was setting up my emails. However I had not allowed the calander app permission to mu online account. So I went into the accounts and clicked add online calender. This brought up the allow permission question for the account I had set up. I clicked OK and the sync started automatically. Then the sync icon was there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked a treat. Thanks for that, what I fool I am not allowing the calendar app to access my online google calendar. When I set it all up I must of missed that. Now I have the sync icon and my events are showing up.